# MPI directive for serial run

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, mpi, openmpi

I added a piece of code to an open source software. My code reads data from a file, copies the data to an std::vector (using push_back) and later uses that vector for some applications. The code works when I run it in serial, however, in parallel I get the following error:

mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 27564 on node alpha exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault)

How can I make MPI to only run the part of the code I added in serial and the rest in parallel? I tried the following but I get the same error.

Update: I used `std::cout` to find out where exactly the code breaks. It turned out when I use the updated value of "normalValue" I get the error.

```
#ifdef HAVE_MPI

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank)

#else

rank = MASTER_NODE;

#endif

if ( rank == MASTER_NODE){
double temp_x=0;
double temp_y=0;
double temp_z=0;
double temp_v=0;

std::ifstream file;
//x,y,z,v are the data members of the class declared in the header file
//...

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    normalValue+=Dir[i]*Dir[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    Dir[i]/=normalValue;// **This is where the I get the error. The problem is related to "normalValue". I get the same error even if I try to use std::cout<<normalValue<<std::endl**
    }


while (file.good())
{

    file >> temp_x >> temp_y >> temp_z>> temp_v;
    x.push_back(temp_x);
    y.push_back(temp_y)
    z.push_back(temp_z);
    v.push_back(temp_v);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of MASTER_NODE ? is it between 0 and MPI_Comm_size of MPI_COMM_WORLD ? If yes, then I am not sure what the mistake is. I would need more information.

Comment: @RonnyBrendel Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes, the value of MASTER_NODE is zero. What information do you need?

Comment: Your code is fine so far. I would need more code and at least stack traces. Did you try to debugging this with a debugging tool?

Comment: @RonnyBrendel Well, no I have not, but I updated the code snippet with the essential parts.

Comment: It's impossible to help without a [mcve]. Also you should present your own attempts of using a debugger.

Comment: @Zulan I used std::cout to find where the code breaks. Please see the update.

Comment: This is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) since it does not compile (not to mention there is no evidence the issue occurs in this snippet, and `Dir` is not declared)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I know! There is no way to make over 800000 lines of codes minimal.

Comment: in this case, you are basically on your own ... use a debugger, or collect stack traces to understand where the crash occurs. i noted vectors `{x,y,z,v}` are set only on rank 0, i guess you need to allocate and send them to the other ranks, but you did not provide the code that takes care of that.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thanks a lot for your remarks. I will try to figure it out.